# Jsonschema, validating object keys with a custom function

Tags: python, jsonschema

I am using [python-jsonschema](https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for json validation. I have an object with localised texts that are specified inside rfc1766 language code keys as followings:

```
"Description": {
    "en": "English Description",
    "sv": "Swedish Description",
    "fr": "French Description"
},
```

[I've read in the documentation](https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.org/en/latest/validate/#validating-formats) that I could use the 'format' attribute to check a custom format using a function. So,I wrote a method which takes a string as a parameter and returns True if it is an RFC1766 language string.

```
@_checks_drafts('rfc1766lang')
def rfc1766lang(instance):
    """some logic, return True if rfc1766"""
```

However I couldn't find any example on how to apply this to do validation on an object key, not a value.

Is this possible?

I have tried something like below but I couldn't succeed

```
rfc1766_string_schema_v2 = {
    'type': 'object',
    'format': 'rfc1766lang',    
    'additionalProperties': False
}
```

I know that it would be much easier if I had the json string as follows. However, this is not an option for now.

```
"Description": [{
    "lan": "en",
    "text": "Description in English"
}, {
    "lan": "sv",
    "name": "Description in Swedish"
}]
```

Comment: I can't even find how to apply your custom format checker to a value, that would help me quite a bit. The link to the documentation you've provided only shows how to use predefined formats.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a very good and relevant question because this is actually part of the [proposed syntax for v5](https://github.com/json-schema/json-schema/wiki/multilingual-meta-data-(v5-proposal)), so the official meta-schema will have to deal with this as well.

JSON Schema cannot specify a "format" for object keys.  The only "validation" JSON Schema supports for object keys is `patternProperties`, which supplies a regular expression.

For language codes, the best you can do is probably something like:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "patternProperties": {
        "^[a-zA-Z]+(-[a-zA-Z]+)*$": {...}
    },
    "additionalProperties": false
}
```

That would limit the data so that it was only allowed properties matching that pattern - but that's not the full validation you're looking for, I'm afraid.